# Pay for Azure VM only when you use?

Tags: azure

I want a virtual system Large (A3) and I am going to use it occasionally. Pricing says $0.308/hr. Does this mean if the system is shutdown, then I don' play anything? What about the storage? I pay extra for that? How much storage I get along with OS?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the licensing costs of a service.

Comment: This is a reasonable question (with an accurate answer), but it's located in the wrong place.

Comment: While this isn't strictly a programming-related question it is related to operating services in Azure.  Management of costs is a common public-cloud related area for most developers because it's sometimes not easy to determine what you pay for and when.

Comment: Actually I wanted to ask this question at azure forum but they sent me here. They have a link to stackoverflow and they ask you to tag 'azure'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to shutdown the VM (either in the Azure Portal or via PowerShell).  It will show as "Stopped (deallocated)". At this point the only charges you would incur would be for the VHD disk images sitting in Azure Blob Storage.

The default VHD sizes are listed [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx) under "Virtual Machines".  These are "thin provisioned" which means you only pay for the actual data contained on the disk image and not the entire size (i.e. you can create a 1TB VHD but if it contains only 10GB of data you would only pay for 10GB).